# Printer needs to be "awaken" before printing

Tags: usb, printing, printer, linux-mint

**Background info:** Xerox Phaser 3140 laser printer connected to a 7th gen. Core i5 desktop computer running updated Linux Mint 18.2 x64 using a USB cable.

**Symptoms:** The first print (after turning the printer on) and following prints within a few minutes work as expected - the pages are printed out after confirming the print dialog (usually from Libre Office or Adobe Reader).
However when printer is left turned on for at least ~20 minutes, the first print afterwards is discarded. The motors in the printer start and run for a few seconds but then they stop and no printing happens. The print dialog needs to be invoked and confirmed once more to make the printer actually print.

**My research:** As the same printer was connected to a Core2 computer running Windows Vista before and this did not happen (the printer was always ready even after leaving it turned on for a long time) I assume this is a Linux driver issue.
The driver shipped with the OS is used. (Native [Xerox printer Driver for Linux](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/phaser-3140/downloads/enza.html?operatingSystem=winxp) from 2009 didn't print here at all and the settings looked the same as in the OS shipped driver.)

There's a "Power Save" setting (set to 5 minutes by default) in printer driver properties that I suspected from causing the problem but after changing it to Off, the problem persists.

**Question:** Is there a way (or a workaround) to make the printer print for the first time (without the false/waking-up print) after it has been turned on for some time? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to connect the printer to some real operating system, with driver support from manufacturer (not 10-years-old), to see if it goes into SUSPEND and then resumes from USB host normally?

Comment: I'm not sure if Windows Vista is a more "real" OS but yes - it worked there fine (see "My research" paragraph). I know it would very likely work in Windows 10 but I'm interested in making it work without changing the OS.

Comment: Vista is not a real OS, it barely can handle any USB activity, and I am not sure if the USB suspend was ever implemented in Vista. First you need to determine if the printer is still OK if suspend option is set. What is so difficult to plug it into any modern WinPC/laptop and try with manufacturer supported driver?

Comment: OK, I can try that with my Win10 Pro laptop. There's a 3-year old Win10 x64 driver download for my printer at Xerox website. I suppose you mean the "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" that's in Device Manager on the Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller 1.0 (Microsoft) tree item...?

Comment: No problem with Windows 10 and a 2015 Lenovo laptop. All USB tree items in Device Manager with the Power Management option have had it enabled. The printer was "heating up" (resuming) for about 20 seconds and then started to print.